# Rest API not sending full content of a file

Tags: rest, sharepoint-hosted-app, sharepoint-rest-api

My requirement is that there is a file called `abc.pdf` in a document library. Depending upon the logged in user and today's date, the downloaded file's name is to be changed. For example, if last name of the logged in user is Karthik, then the  name of the downloaded file must be `abc_Karthik_13-01-17.pdf`.

So, I am trying to complete the requirement by getting content of the file in a JavaScript variable and download it using msSaveOrOpenBlob method. Below are relevant code snippets:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('<relative url>')/openbinarystream",
    binaryStringResponseBody: true,
    success: function (data) {
        var blobData = data;
        var blobObject = new Blob([blobData]);
        window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blobObject, 'abc_Karthik_13-01-17.pdf')
    },
    error: function (error) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(error))
    }
});
```

The strange issue that I am facing is that I am not getting the complete contents of the pdf file in the `data` variable. But when I see fiddler trace, I am able to see the full contents in the body. Below is the screenshot of fiddler for that ajax request. You can see that the vertical scroll bar is so big. My question is : **Why am I not getting the complete contents of the file in the `data` variable but I can see the complete content in fiddler trace ?**

[image]

Comment: try /_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('<relative url>')/$value

Comment: @sekhar thanks for the comment but I already tried it and it is not working. I am facing same issue with `$value`